# Titanium studio disable enter key in android keybord

Tags: android, titanium

I seem to get stuck on a problem i can't seem to find a answer for.
I have a Textarea in titanium studio where you can enter your name and if you click the button it safes it into the database but i want to disable the enter key in android keyboard or change it action similar to a space button so it wont mess it up when inserting into the database.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Below is my code :

```
var textArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    hintText: 'Enter Name',
    left:10,
    width:200,
    height:40,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for your textarea?

Comment: Does the solution works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **add Keyboard properties** to your textarea.

```
var textArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    hintText: 'Enter Name',
    left:10,
    width:200,
    height:40,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_GO     
});
```

You can set *keyboardType* and *returnKeyType* values as per your needs.

Check these two properties :

- **keyboardType** : Keyboard type to display when this text area is focused. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-property-keyboardType
- **returnKeyType** :  Specifies the text to display on the keyboard Return key when this text area is focused. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-property-returnKeyType

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think he want to disable the done button. Your answer makes confusion :O. Also he clearly states that he want to enter a name and your code will display a number key pad!!!

Comment: Sorry bit late was bussy the returnkeytype was what i needed.
@Anand he also provided the links for the other statements so that wasn't really a ploblem

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to just dismiss the soft keyboard on pressing the return key. You can use the [`returnKeyType`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-property-returnKeyType) property of textArea. This will allow you to change the type of return key. As per your requirement you may try [Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-RETURNKEY_DONE).

You can also override the `return` event to disable the enter key of your soft keyboard.

To override the return key event, you can try the following

```
textArea.addEventListener('return', function(e){
    //TODO:Your code here, if any
});
```

Hope it helped you!